# Setting an array in Rails params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I have a multiselect dropdown that results in a redirect to URLs that include params like this:

```
period_id%5B%5D=14&period_id%5B%5D=15
```

In some circumstances, I need to set these params in my controller. I've tried

```
params[:period_id[]] = ['25']
```

and

```
params['period_id[]'] = ['25']
```

but this doesn't work.

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: You want your controller to behave as if those params were passed to you or you're constructing a hash of params to pass to link_to (or similar) ?

Comment: I want the controller to behave as if those params were passed to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

params is a standard ruby Hash so anything can be set as value.

try: `params[:period_id] = [14,15,16...]`

Comment: This doesn't work for me; when I read the params into an array, using params[:period_id].collect { |s| s.to_i }, they aren't returned in the same way as they are when they are supplied in the URL above.

Comment: Didn't understand you. Btw. there is shortcut for your `.collect {|s| s.to_i}` call. Do it this way: `params[:period_id].collect(&:to_i)`